# How can I add ImageJ to my build path in Eclipse, and where can I find the ImageJ .jar file?

Tags: java, eclipse, imagej

I am extremely novice when it comes to using external libraries in my code. I have been looking for an embarrassing amount of time on how to actually add this particular library to my build path.

My main issue is that I cannot find the .jar file, or I don't know how to go from a cloned git repository to a jar file.

Any help would be immensely appreciated.

If it makes a difference, I am interested this [Non Local Means Denoise Class](http://imagej.net/Non_Local_Means_Denoise), along with a few others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the source code for that project, you can build it yourself (if, for instance, you're using maven just do "mvn install" and then look in the "target" directory for the jar).

Regardless of how you get the jar, once you have it you can add it to the project in Eclipse by right-clicking on the project, going to "build path"... "configure build path" and then adding it as a library.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'm asking specifically how to get the jar for ImageJ. I have downloaded several of what I thought were the source files but I don't know where to go from there in obtaining a jar file.

Comment: I do have Maven installed, but using mvn install is confusing because I don't know what my target directory is, or if I even have the correct source for ImageJ

Comment: Run mvn install from the same directory that contains the file pom.xml (it will probably also contain the src directory). After you run it you should see a target directory, and that target directory will probably contain the imageJ jar file.

Comment: Alternatively, google "imagej jar download", which seems to generate some worthwhile results. :-)